# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.01

Tags: entity-framework, linq

This is function that takes two `List<int>` and update corresponding tables at database. When I run both functions using threads **T1** and **T2** , then it shows me exception at the second foreach loop:

> "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be
>   used"

I already used query like

```
var res = ctx.EmailDBs.Include(x => x.EmailDBid == id);
```

but it's not working.
Please share something to persist the `ctx` connection until both methods are executed.

```
 public static void UpdateEmail(List<int> invalidEmailToUpdate, List<int> validEmailToUpdate)
 {
     using (OnliveMTAEntities ctx = new OnliveMTAEntities())
     {

         Thread T1, T2;

         T1 = new Thread(() =>
         {
             foreach (int id in invalidEmailToUpdate)
             {
                 var res = ctx.EmailDBs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmailDBid == id);
                 res.Status = 6;
             }
         });

         T1.Start();
         Thread.Sleep(100);

         T2 = new Thread(() =>
         {
             foreach (int id in validEmailToUpdate)
             {
                 var res = ctx.EmailDBs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmailDBid == id);
                 res.Status = 7;
             }
         });

         T2.Start();

         ctx.SaveChanges();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using threads here?

Comment: @Default Maybe he want paralel update ( thus faster almost two times)? I Suppose that two lists are distinct, so no problems will arise.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich Do you have proof that this would be faster? To me, it looks like one connection and that the majority of the algorithm here is reading. Thus it would be limited by the IO limitations of that connection. I fail to see how threading would improve it. Also, IIRC Object- and DbContexts are not thread safe.

Comment: @Default Maybe I'm wrong - but I think it's like that: he is reading  from table, so there is only read-read access and that is ok. Db engine will handle it and you have 2 parallel threads, so I think there could be slightly improved performance.

Comment: @Default: But, there is another question - is it really necesary to do it this way? Because if you are updating almost entire table, maybe it would be faster to grab all results to memory and perform changes locally, then SaveChanges. EDIT: Moreover, if there will be lot of emails, it would be better to use Stored Procedure. It depends - we don't have enough info to answer correcly to question "how we can do that faster?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until both threads **T1** and **T2** are fully completed. Only then you can save dataContext `ctx.SaveChanges();`

For that purpose is method called **Join()** ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Use it like that:

```
// previous code here
T2.Start();

// wait for threads to be done
T1.Join();
T2.Join();

// now both of them are done
ctx.SaveChanges();
// end of using(...) and other code
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention: using both `Join()`, you can get rid of      `Thread.Sleep(100);`. I believe that this is the reason why you got error on second thread. That call will pause execution of current thread (which will start T2) for 100ms and during that time T1 succeded to complete it's work.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but am little bit confused.  If we are waiting for t1 thread to be complete like T1.Join() for T2,  and  and T2.Join() for ctx.SaveChanges() then what is the banefit of parallel execution ???

Comment: @ShabiZaidi Context, in which your function will be usually running is really important . If you have very large table `EmailDBs` and you are changing relatively small amount of records, since function `FirstOrDefault()` works in O(n), then total execution of your function can be something about half of time compared to version without Threads. Please, read carefully comments under your question and if you write extended info (how many rows in EmailDBs are you expecting, how many of them you are actually update, etc.) in your question, I will help you find appropriate solution. (Pls notify me)